# XPath/XSLT Remove Empty Tags

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

I would like to remove tags which contain only whitespace/newline/tab chars, as below:

```
<p>    </p>
```

How would you do this using xpath functions and xslt templates?

Comment: Good question, +1. It is possible to correctly produce the wanted result using the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern -- overriding the identity rule.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**This transformation (overriding the [identity rule](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)):**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[not(*) and not(text()[normalize-space()])]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied to the following XML document**:

```
<t>
 <a>
  <b>
    <c/>
  </b>
 </a>
 <p></p>
 <p>  </p>
 <p>Text</p>
</t>
```

**correctly produces the wanted result**:

```
<t>
   <a>
      <b/>
   </a>
   <p>Text</p>
</t>
```

**Remember**: Using and overriding the identity rule/template is the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern. It is the right choice for a variety of problems where most of the nodes are to be copied unchanged and only some specific nodes need be altered, deleted, renamed, ..., etc.

**Note**: @Abel in his comment recommends that some bits of this solution need to be further explained:

> For the uninitiated or curious: `not(*)` means: not having an child
>   element; `not(text()[normalize-space()])` means: not having a text-node
>   with non - white-space-only text.

Comment: For the uninitiated or curious: `not(*)` means: not having a child element; `not(text()[normalize-space()])` means: not having a text-node with text.

Comment: @Abel: Thank you, I'll explain this in the answer.

Comment: That's great, thanks Dimitre. I'm still somewhat a beginner with XSLT and I keep comming across stuff like this that makes be go wow. I think i need to find a good book. Thanks again for the awesome explanation, SO needs more of this.

Comment: @Kyle: You are welcome. I have provided links to some books and resources here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online/341589#341589