# How to remove empty tags in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

This is the XML file I am using:

```
 <data>
     <addressrecord id = "1bdd3154dc78bd75c5f1983d640005a6" type = "person">
     <category mode="main">customer</category>
     <firstname>Ann-margret</firstname>
     <lastname>Carlsson</lastname>
     <companyname></companyname>
         <address name="main">
           <street>s:t Gertrudsvägen 156</street>
           <zip>59341</zip>
           <city>Västervik</city>
          </address>
     <phone subtype="home">0490-36328</phone>
     <email></email>
   </addressrecord>
</data>
```

I am trying to put this XML to XSL in a table format, not in HTML table format.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a question, it's a statement. Turn it into a question (via the `edit` link on your question) by telling us what **exactly** what you're trying to do, how you're trying to do it, and what problems you're having... and somebody will try and help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749917/xpath-xslt-remove-empty-tags.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you wants to keep all the things as it is instead of "email" element because it is empty, you wants to remove it. Here is the solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" exclude-result-prefixes="m">

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[not(child::node())]"/>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```